# ListGrid disable fields dropdown for sorting, freezing, editing

Tags: drop-down-menu, smartgwt, listgrid

I'm developing web-app where I use the SmartGWT Listgrid. When I create and visualize the Listgrid there is arrow dropdown for sorting, configuring sort, etc. Searching in the documentation I didn't find property to disable this dropdown. Does anyone know how to disable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I don't want to use the sort and the header menu I use to do:

```
myGrid.setShowSortArrow(SortArrow.NONE);
```

Also for the header menu:

```
myGrid.setShowHeaderContextMenu(false);
myGrid.setShowHeaderMenuButton(false);
```

I also often cancel the clik event and the double click event on the header

And eventually I declared the field not sortable with `theField.setCanSort(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is applied at column level & not at grid level. So if you want to turn sorting off on a particular column, you can try the following:

```
listGridField.setCanSort(false);
```

Comment: In latest versions you can disable the "configure sort" with setCanMultiSort(false)